# How to print a whole paragraph of text by referencing its subheading?

Tags: python, database, string, class, text

I am making a simple app that gives the user in depth information on a specific aircraft caution/warning when they press that specific button. I am pretty new and this is probably a very basic problem, but I simply don't know how to do it.

I'm not sure if the best way to organise the text data is to maybe put each caution/warning under its own string variable in a separate `.py` file, or maybe make a class with different modules for each caution/warning with the module just being string info. Maybe a dictionary? Maybe the best way is to have it as a text file???

For each of the caution/warnings there will be approximately 200 words describing the problem associated with it and a solution.

A very short example of what I mean is: If someone pressed on the "Battery" caution, the button calls for the `get_text` function in `main.py` and sends it the button's `id`. The `get_text` uses that `id` that was sent to it and then pulls the text from `AOM.py` or `.txt` or whatever. The information will then be displayed on the page and would be approximately 200 words about what the issue with the battery is and how to fix it. (I am purposely disregarding the need to change screens in my example here as I know how to do that). I'm just leaving as a `print()` for now.

I have a min reproducible example here if someone could please help me out? Thank you very much.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import AOM

class CautionPanelScreen(Screen):
    pass
class TextScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self):
        # get the screen manager from the main.kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = 'text_screen'

    def get_text(self, caution):
        print(AOM.caution)             # this is where i am stuck, I dont know how to ref the data...

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include caution_panel_screen.kv
#:include text_screen.kv
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#EEEEEE")
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            CautionPanelScreen:
                name: "caution_panel_screen"
                id: caution_panel_screen
```

caution_panel_screen.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<CautionPanelScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        flt_data_recorder: flt_data_recorder.__self__
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            id: row_1
            pos_hint: {"top": .9, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .1
            spacing: 5, 5
            Button:
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
                markup: True
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else .5
                font_size: '12sp'
                id: pri_inv
                halign: 'center'
                text: "[color=#FFF300]PRI INV[/color]"
                on_release:
                    app.get_text(pri_inv)
            Button:
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
                markup: True
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else .5
                font_size: '12sp'
                id: l_ac_bus
                halign: 'center'
                text: "[color=#FFF300]L AC BUS[/color]"
                on_release:
                    app.get_text(l_ac_bus)
            Button:
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
                markup: True
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else .5
                font_size: '12sp'
                id: emer_lts_disarmed
                halign: 'center'
                text: "[color=#FFF300]EMER LTS\nDISARMED[/color]"
                on_release:
                    app.get_text(emer_lts_disarmed)
```

AOM.py

```
#THIS IS JUST THE DATA PAGE AND CAN BE LAID OUT IN ANY WAY, dictionary, variables, txt, module, functions...
pri_inv = "all the things assosicated with primary inverter"
left_ac_bus = "all the stuff needed for info on left ac buses"
emer_lts_disarmed = "evertyhing on emergency  lights"
```

EDIT:
Will I have to store the text on my main.py? Or can I have it separate, like maybe in a word doc?

Comment: I would keep it as `dictionary` or `list`. Or as file JSON, CSV, YAMl which I would load to `dictionary` or `list`. And with dictionary/list you can use `for`-loop to create `Buttons` in Python code - so code will be shorter and when you add new data to dictonary/list then it will automatically create more buttons at start.

Comment: Thanks for your respomse @furas, I am trying to add it in a dictionary, but because every caution/warning has about 200 word description, it looks quite messy. Can I make a file with all of the caution/warning descriptions and then have each description bundled so that I can call them individually? Is that possible?

Comment: it doesn't matter how it looks in dictionary - besides if you put every `caution/warning` in new line in dictionary then it should look the same as you already have. You don't have to write all dictionary in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep it as dictionary

**AOM.py**

```
data = {
    'pri_inv': "all the things assosicated with primary inverter",
    'left_ac_bus': "all the stuff needed for info on left ac buses",
    'emer_lts_disarmed': "evertyhing on emergency  lights",
}
```

And `Button` should use string in `get_text()` in `on_release`

```
     on_release:
         app.get_text("pri_inv")


     on_release:
         root.get_text("left_ac_bus")


     on_release:
         app.get_text("emer_lts_disarmed")
```

and then code should use this string to get text from `AOM.data`

```
    def get_text(self, caution):
        print(AOM.data[caution])
```

---

Maybe later I would use `AOM.data` to generate `Button` so I would keep button's text also in `AOM.data`

```
data = {
    'pri_inv': ["PRI INV", "all the things assosicated with primary inverter"],
    'left_ac_bus': ["L AC BUS", "all the stuff needed for info on left ac buses"],
    'emer_lts_disarmed': ["EMER LTS\nDISARMED", "evertyhing on emergency  lights"],
}
```

and then it would need to use index `[1]` to get text

```
    def get_text(self, caution):
        print(AOM.data[caution][1])
```

---

Or it could keep in nested dictionares

```
data = {
    'pri_inv': {
         "button_text": "PRI INV", 
         "text": "all the things assosicated with primary inverter",
    },
    'left_ac_bus': {
         "button_text": "L AC BUS", 
         "text": "all the stuff needed for info on left ac buses",
    },
    'emer_lts_disarmed': {
         "button_text": "EMER LTS\nDISARMED", 
         "text": "evertyhing on emergency  lights",
    },
}
```

and then it would need to use `["text"]` to get text

```
    def get_text(self, caution):
        print(AOM.data[caution]["text"])
```

---

if buttons would have other unique values then I would also keep them
in dictionary.